# QThread with fork() don't emit signals

Tags: multithreading, qt, fork, qthread

I'm doing a school work and I need to implement multiples fork's and show when the computer create and delete the child process in QT, ok I'm doing this with QThread and the thread send a signal to my MainWindow and the image appers, but the QT just send the father's signal, what's the problem?

```
void MyThread::run() {
time_t tempo_real;
tempo_real = time( (time_t *) 0);

cout << "Pai criado com PID: " << getpid() << " Em: " << time( (time_t *) 0) - tempo_real << "segundos." << endl;
emit adicionar(0);
this->sleep(14);
pid_t filhoUm;
filhoUm = fork();
switch(filhoUm) {
case -1:
    terminate();
    break;
case 0:
    cout << "Filho 1 criado com PID: " << getpid() << " Em: " << time( (time_t *) 0) - tempo_real << "segundos." << endl;
    emit adicionar(1);
    this->sleep(12);
    pid_t netoUm;
    netoUm = fork();
    switch(netoUm) {
    case -1:
        terminate();
        break;
    case 0:
        cout << "Neto 1 criado com PID: " << getpid() << " Em: " << time( (time_t *) 0) - tempo_real << "segundos." << endl;
        emit adicionar(3);
        this->sleep(12);
        cout << "Neto 1 is dead com PAI: " << getppid() << " Em: " << time( (time_t *) 0) - tempo_real << "segundos." << endl;
        emit adicionar(8);
        terminate();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    this->sleep(18);
    cout << "Filho 1 is dead!" << " Em: " << time( (time_t *) 0) - tempo_real << "segundos." << endl;
    emit adicionar(6);
    terminate();
    break;
default:
    this->sleep(2);
    pid_t filhoDois;
    filhoDois = fork();
    switch(filhoDois) {
    case -1:
        terminate();
        break;
    case 0:
        cout << "Filho 2 criado com PID: " << getpid() << " Em: " << time( (time_t *) 0) - tempo_real << "segundos." << endl;
        emit adicionar(2);
        this->sleep(14);
        pid_t netoDois;
        netoDois = fork();
        switch(netoDois) {
        case -1:
            terminate();
            break;
        case 0:
            cout << "Neto 2 criado com PID: " << getpid() << " Em: " << time( (time_t *) 0) - tempo_real << "segundos." << endl;
            emit adicionar(4);
            this->sleep(18);
            cout << "Neto 2 is dead com PAI: " << getppid() << " Em: " << time( (time_t *) 0) - tempo_real << "segundos." << endl;
            emit adicionar(9);
            terminate();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        this->sleep(16);
        cout << "Filho 2 is dead!" << " Em: " << time( (time_t *) 0) - tempo_real << "segundos." << endl;
        emit adicionar(7);
        terminate();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    this->sleep(44);
    cout << "Pai is dead!" << " Em: " << time( (time_t *) 0) - tempo_real << "segundos." << endl;
    emit adicionar(5);
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think fork()-ing a process that has a Qt GUI active is going to work well -- a GUI Qt process has connections to the windowing system, etc, and duplicating those connections to another process is going to cause confusion all around.  You might get away with using QProcess to spawn a non-GUI sub-process and then calling fork() from there, but at that point you're probably better off avoiding fork() entirely and just using QProcess alone to spawn new processes.

Comment: Qt is neither designed nor tested for forking. You're on your own. The only sane suggestion is: don't do it.